# Insertion in sorted doubly linked list

Tags: java, insert, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am given the pointer to the head node of a sorted doubly linked list and an integer to insert into the list.I am told to create a node and insert it into the appropriate position in the list such that its sorted order is maintained. The head node might be NULL.

Sample Input

NULL , data = 2

NULL <-- 2 <--> 4 <--> 6 --> NULL  , data = 5

Sample Output

NULL <-- 2 --> NULL

NULL <-- 2 <--> 4 <--> 5 <--> 6 --> NULL

I tried the above problem.But My program is terminating due to timeout.What am I doing wrong in the below code. Assume Node class and main function is already there. Many Thanks in advance!!

```
Node SortedInsert(Node head,int data) {

    Node newn = new Node();

    newn.data = data;
    newn.prev=null;
    newn.next = null;

    Node ptr = head;
    Node nex=head.next;

    while(ptr!=null && nex!=null) {
        if(ptr.data<=newn.data && nex.data>=newn.data) {
            newn.next = nex;
            newn.prev = ptr;
            nex.prev = newn;
            ptr.next = newn;
        }            
        else {
            nex=nex.next;
            ptr=ptr.next;
        }
    }

    if(ptr!=null && nex==null) {
        if(ptr.data>=newn.data) {
            newn.next=ptr;
            ptr.prev=newn;
            newn.prev=null;
            head=newn;
        }
        else {
            ptr.next=newn;
            newn.prev = head;
        }
    }

    if(head==null) {
        head = newn; 
    }

    return head;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly simple:
You are not breaking out of the loop after succesfully inserting. Therefore it keeps looping over the position it inserts the node in. Make a tiny change:

```
if(ptr.data>=newn.data)
{
    newn.next=ptr;
    ptr.prev=newn;
    newn.prev=null;
    head=newn;
    break;
}
```

However, you have some redundant code written. This is shorter and doesn't contain redundant code:

```
Node SortedInsert(Node head,int data) {

    Node newn = new Node();
    newn.data = data;  

    Node ptr = head;

    if (ptr == null) {
        head = newn;

    } else if ( ptr.data > newn.data ) {
        newn.next = ptr;
        ptr.prev = newn;
        head = newn;

    } else {
        Node nex = head.next;

        while (nex != null && nex.data <= newn.data) {
            ptr = nex;
            nex = nex.next;
        }

        ptr.next = newn;
        newn.prev = ptr;

        if (nex != null) {
            nex.prev = newn;
            newn.next = nex;
        }
    }

    return head;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the head node is null you'll geta NullPointerException while trying to get the next/prev nodes. You should check that first:

```
Node sortedInsert(Node head, int data) {
    Node newn = new Node();
    newn.data = data;
    //Basic case: the list is empty, so the head is null
    if (head==null) {
        return newn;
    }
    //If node is not null
    Node aux= head;
    Node auxPrev;
    while (aux!=null && aux.data<data) {
        auxPrev=aux;
        aux=aux.next;
    }
    //auxPrev will be null if we are going to insert in the first position
    if (auxPrev!=null)
        auxPrev.next=newn;
        newn.prev=auxPrev;
        head=newn;
    }
    //aux will be null if we insert in the last position
    if (aux!=null) {
        aux.prev=newn;
        newn.next=aux;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: At declaration you are naming the variable "aux1", but then referring as "aux" to it. And in the second if from last there is "nexwn" which should be "newn". And you are not returning head in most cases.

Comment: No problem. A very clean and nice solution else.